# Substring Length cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I'm separating a string by first name and last name.

I equate the last word to the last name. I equate the remainder to the firstname.

This string can be empty or null.
I'm checking for null return.

but in case the string is empty I get the following error.

or I get an error when only the name.
**for example; string test = "Jack";**

How can I do this in a single line without adding another "if else" control to the code?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7lr07G

```
[System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length]
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
```

Comment: To find the first name, you're using `string.LastIndexOf` to find the last space, then using `string.Substring` to take everything up to that point. To find the last name, you're splitting the string on spaces and taking the last component. Both of those are valid approaches, but why do *both*? Either use `LastIndexOf` and then use `Substring` to get both the first and last name, or use a single `string.Split`

Comment: You should use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead of string == null or string != null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `test.LastIndexOf(" ")` which returns -1 if there is no space in `test`. Have a look at [MSDN - String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0)

You can use [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0)

```
var firstname = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(test) && test.Contains(" ") 
        ? test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf(" ")) 
        : string.IsNullOrEmpty(test) ? string.Empty : test;
var lastname = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(test) && test.Contains(" ") 
        ? test.Split(' ').Last() 
        : string.Empty;
```

to check if there is a space in `test`.

I recommend using [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0) instead of `test != null`.

Comment: if *** string test ="Jack" *** then last name is Jack.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
    //string test = "Jack ";
    //string test = "Jack";
    string test = "Jack Nelsson";
    var firstname = string.Empty;
    var lastname =  string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))
    {
        var index =  test.LastIndexOf(" ");
        if (index < 0 || index >= test.Length - 1)
        {
            firstname = test.TrimEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            firstname = test.Substring(0, index);
            lastname =  test.Substring(index + 1);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(firstname);
    Console.WriteLine(lastname);
```

By default, we set string.Empty. If test has a string, we search last whitespace and store in a variable to use later.

If no namespace found: set firstname to all text.
If whitespace found at the end of the string: set firstname to all text without ending spaces. We need to check this case because substring with index+1 fail in this case.
In other case, split the string in that point.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `IndexOf` as little as possible, because I always end up confusing myself with the indices. So here's different approach:

```cs
string firstname = "";
string lastname = "";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    var parts = name.Split(' ');
    lastname = parts[parts.Length-1];
    firstname = string.Join(" ", parts.Take(parts.Length-1));
}
```

It simply splits using space, then makes the last part the last name and join the others as the first name.

**EDIT**
I just saw Mighty Badaboom's solution and was inspired by the use of `Last`. Here's a version with even fewer integers involved:

```cs
string firstname = "";
string lastname = "";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    var parts = name.Split(' ');
    lastname = parts.Last();
    firstname = string.Join(" ", parts.SkipLast(1));
}
```

SkipLast requires .NET standard 2.1. If on older standard you can go for:

```cs
    firstname = string.Join(" ", parts.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string test = "Jack Daniels";
    
    var firstname = string.IsNullOrEmpty(test)
        ? string.Empty
        : (test.Contains(" ") ? (test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf(" "))).Trim() : test);
    var lastname = string.IsNullOrEmpty(test)
        ? string.Empty
        : (test.Contains(" ") ? (test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf(" ")).Trim()) : string.Empty);
    
    Console.WriteLine("firstname>>" + firstname);
    Console.WriteLine("lastname>>" + lastname);
```